# Logic of Java barcode reader for libraryMS

Tags: java, swing, logic, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have to do a library Magement System in Java Swing. I had done it well with all your supports. Thank you all. Now this s/w needs to identify book and students by barcode (1d). I couldn't get a perfect logic from any where. I have read in SO and other web. I got some logic. But the vision is not clear.

I know this.
 bar-code scanner output to port - listen to key strock- need Interface

My doubt is

- What the order of the logic flow. ?
- do i have to add any lib/jar files to do it.
- how to implement this?

I have read a focused text field is needed. How to know did the scanner end key stocks.

I am totally confused. Sorry for reading poor English. I will make up this

Advanced thanks for all your support .

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the picture from the reader (depends on the hardware, you might need to use the proprietary API or whatever it requires)
2. Use a barcode reading library to 'parse' the picture. (like [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), which maybe can access a camera?)
3. which will give you the number hidden in the barcode.